# How to add copyright information in each file of Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, copyright-display

I need to add Copyright information on top of each and every file of my Rails source code. 
For Eg. **Just like Xcode does when you do ios development**.

Like:

```
**********
// Copyright (c) 2012 
// List of Authors
*********
```

Comment: Do you mean how can you add this automatically, or how you can do it in the first place? Comments in Ruby begin with `#`.

Comment: This is a function of your editing software, or something you can easily script using a batch or shell script. It's not something you want Rails to do automatically. I recommend it be moved to http://superuser.com/.

Comment: @tadman It right now has hundreds of files so I cannot manually doing it.

Comment: +1 for @theTinMan, you need to write a macro or something in your editor to do this by default when you edit a file/create. A good editor is Notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is to include a file in the base of the project called LICENSE, and include all the copyright information for all files in the project there.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your editor of choice, which you should specify. Many editors support some sort of file templates and, as an example, [here's](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/file-templates.html) how to do it in Rubymine.

Comment: My editor is sublime text2. I dint know if there exists macro for it. I never looked into it.

Answer (score -1):

For views, you can put it at the top of the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file, and that should include it in every view, except for partials (those you have to do by hand I think).

Not sure there is a way to do it automatically for anything else.. Might be wrong though.

Comment: Nope I need it on the source code not on the view.

Comment: Each type of file will require a different comment block. `erb` is significantly different from `rb` for example.